# Eclipse: Filter "open resource" based on path as well as name?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

As the title suggests, is there any way to filter the “Open Resource” dialog based on path? For example, so I can navigate to `c/foo` or `d/foo` without having to up/down through the `{a,b}/foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but it might be possible to do with 3.6M7, since
support for paths was recently added to the open resource dialog - see this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86973).

Comment: That looks like exactly what I want. Thanks.