# Eclipse: How do I quickly open a folder (in the package, project or resource explorer) with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, ansible

I am used to quickly search and open files with CTRL+SHIFT+R - Open Resource. However, Open Resource does not match folders. I would need to do the same for folders within the project, or alternatively, for matching files with part of their project-relative path.

The use case is working with Ansible roles, where all files are named "main.yml" and are located in a hierarchical folder structure:

```
-project
   +-roles
       +-apache
           |
           +---tasks
           |     +----main.yml 
           +---handlers
           |     +----main.yml 
           +---vars
           |     +----main.yml
```

And I need to quickly open the various main.yml files by searching for their path e.g. typing something like

```
CTRL + SHIFT + <<insert key here>>
```

then

```
apache/vars
```

and obtain a short list including apache/vars/main.yml

Is there any feature or plugin providing such functionality? It would also be useful for opening maven pom.xml files and the like...

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer: related to [Eclipse: Filter "open resource" based on path as well as name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812352)

Since Eclipse 3.7, path-based matches in Open Resource (CTRL + SHIFT + R) are allowed either writing

- the relative subpath (e.g.roles/apache/tasks/)
- an expression (e.g. *apache/ )

So basically the quickest approach would be the latter

```
CTRL + SHIFT + R
```

then

```
*/<<role>>/
```

I still wonder if there is a quicker way to avoid typing the initial */ and the final /

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't exactly what you want but you can use CTRL+H and go to 'File Search' tab.

You can add new scope to search file only from directory what you are interested. Also you can specify type of searching file.